# How can I build WooCommerce products collections?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to build products collections similar to AliExpress,Amazon, Etsy and other collections.

Comment: please tell us real example of collection?

Comment: Hi Muhammad, plz check http://sale.aliexpress.com/__pc/aliexpresscollections.htm

Comment: Please read about what kinds of questions are [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you three ways:

1. You could create new taxonomy called collections, each term would be a collection. You can extend it for your needs by adding custom fields to collection taxonomy terms i.e. image, relations with specific brands ( which also can be created as taxonomy ). 
   To make final render adjustments, you will have to override archive.php template for your collection taxonomy - i.e. taxonomy-collection.php or taxonomy-collections.php ( depending on slug you choose to use )
2. You could create new custom post type collections, and then create for product post type additional custom field, that would list in dropdown ( multiselect ) or multiple checkboxes all collections.

You will then need to override single.php template for single custom post type view, i.e. single-collection.php

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ for templates reference.

3. You could find and install some plugin ( there is a decent number of such ) that offer extending WooCommerce in terms of having brands and collections attached.

I would suggest first approach, or second if you are decent in WordPress and WooCommerce development. Third is at first easiest, but usually lacks of flexibility and customization, since it is not your code.

Comment: I have searched for a good plugin but couldn't find any practical ones. I am gonna explore the first approach. Thanks

Comment: I also couldn't find any plugin for collections that @niklaz refers to. All plugins called WooCommerce Collections, appear to be relate to different thing suchs as an option to save items to a wish list (called a collection), or changing the image for a product on the product archives to combine multiple products into that one image. But none seem to address what the author was looking for. There are plugins for brands however.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't Grouped products work for you (or anyone searching here)?

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-products/#section-12

> ```
> Go to: WooCommerce > Products > Add New.
> Enter a Title for the Grouped product, e.g., Back to School set
> Scroll down to Product Data and select Grouped from the dropdown. The price and several other fields disappear. This is normal because a
> Grouped Product is a collection of ‘child products’, which is where
> you add this information.
> Publish.
>
> The Grouped product is still an empty group. To this Grouped product,
> you need to:
>
> -Create products and add them
> -Add existing child products
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make collections like those in shopify, for example, grouping products by attributes, or a certain word contained in the title. There is a plugin called WooCommerce Collection by WooExperts. Unfortunately it is a paid plugin. I will give the link below to avoid confusion with another plugin called WooCommerce Collections.

I am not in anyway affiliated to them, I simply use it and it solved this issue for me.

Here is the link: https://wooexperts.com/plugins/woocommerce-collection/